# Choosing a discrete distribution

Tags: distributions

Initially modelled as a normal distribution, I'm now trying to capture the probability that human judgments take on a scale of -100 to 100 (arbitrary discrete judgements) using some kind of discrete distribution that's bounded. The distribution has to be centred around a specified mean and SD, but I'm not sure what kind of distribution I could use. Categorical? Multinomial?

I'm not well versed in statistics so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you tell us more about your data? What is it? Why can't you just use Gaussian? You probably are not assuming that those “judgments” are discrete by nature?

Comment: Started with Gaussian, but say participants can choose on an integer scale of -100 to 100 (not 99.3453), and it must be bounded, then a Gaussian doesn't capture this. As for the data, participants are asked to make confidence judgments on cause-effect trials.

Comment: And you assume that people in their heads have a scale consisting of exactly 201 points, so they can like something at exactly 50 points or 51 points, but anything in between is impossible..?

Comment: You can use a beta distribution latent variable Y ( for rating in ppls head - @Tim suggestion), but then you observe only the integer version of it , X=[Y].  Now do maximum likelihood on beta parameters but observing only rounded Y.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a ruler and read from it that something measures 8cm and 2mm, you *don't* assume that the measurement is exact. You assume it's approximate, with some measurement error. The same with measuring things in social sciences. When using the Likert scale, we don't assume that people can have only 5, 7, 201, etc possible states that are measured, but we use it to approximately measure the underlying phenomenon. So in most cases, you don't need a discrete distribution for such cases, the same as we don't use discrete distributions for things like size, weight, time, etc while neither of them is measured with infinite permission. Discrete distributions are needed for inherently discrete things, like counts.